# Gitlab to Github. Private token equivalent

Tags: github, oauth-2.0, gitlab, github-api, github-enterprise

Our organization is moving away from Gitlab to Github enterprise. and this would involve authentication specific changes for our app.

Our app includes a front end. With every event on the front end, an api* call is made. This API in turn currently hits Gitlab (using gitlab's api) and a private token to commit/branch/push/pull on the repo.

Now, I am trying to work up a similar structure when we migrate to github. From what I have read, github uses oAuth2.0 to authenticate.

Following the documentation, I have followed following steps until now :

1. Created an organization.
2. Added a sample repo to it.
3. Registered my api* (the entity that interacts with the front end) with the organization. This helped me generated a client_id and client_secret.

Now, I have been trying to retrieve an oAuth token using github v3 api but I end up getting an exception :

`"message": "Requires authentication"`

So I am pretty confused now on where to go from here. May be I understood it all wrong ?

If somebody could aide me with this or suggest an alternative, that shall be great.